# How to log actions in container and child containers in react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Sorry if the question is not clear! new to react/redux!

I am responsible for an app that lives in a larger react application. We use the same redux store. Something like this:

> - App
>
>   - Child App 1
>   - Child App 2
>
>     - MyApp
>
>       - Feature1
>       - Feature2
>       - Feature3

I would want to have some logging functions (without installing a new package) at the end of every action. These logger functions would actually hit the backend to log some information in the server. I only want this for the `MyApp` container and any child containers of `MyApp`. I've read about middlewares but I can't modify the main store or main app, not sure if I can add a middleware to `MyApp` alone.

I'm pretty much trying to find a way to do this without having to add the same function to every action for every `Feature`.

Didn't paste the code because `MyApp` is just a simple container. Not creating a store there.

Comment: Maybe [redux logger](https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger)

Comment: Sorry. I'll update my comment, but don't want to add any npm packages. Want to do everything from `MyApp`

Comment: [redux dev tool](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) is by far the best and no extra packages needed. You can add a build check in your store (dev or production) and add the dev tool as middleware.

Comment: Can I add a middleware only to MyApp and the children of MyApp?

Comment: @raygo no, you can't. if you know what actions myApp dispatches you can add a middleware (`store=>next=>action=>next(action)`) that logs only these actions.